# Finding the answer to an integral

Tags: integration

How can I find the answer to the following integral?
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{2\pi} \cos(m\varphi)\cos(n\varphi)\cos(l\varphi) \,d\varphi
\end{equation}

Comment: Answer: By using the addition formula $2\cos a\cos b=\cos(a+b)+\cos(a-b)$, twice, and the fact that $\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(k\varphi)d\varphi$ equals $0$ for every integer $k\ne0$ and $2\pi$ if $k=0$.

Answer (score 3):

For such problems, use the linearisation formulae:
$$2\cos a\cos b =\cos(a+b)+\cos(a-b)$$
and the like for $2\sin a\sin b$ and $2\sin a \cos b$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \cos(m\varphi)\cos(n\varphi)\cos(l\varphi) \,d\varphi$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi} 2\cos(m\varphi)\cos(n\varphi)\cos(l\varphi) \,d\varphi$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi} \left(\cos(m+n)\varphi+\cos(m-n)\varphi\right)\cos(l\varphi) \,d\varphi$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi} \left(\cos(m+n)\varphi\cos(l\varphi)+\cos(m-n)\varphi\cos(l\varphi)\right) \,d\varphi$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^{2\pi} \left(2\cos(m+n)\varphi\cos(l\varphi)+2\cos(m-n)\varphi\cos(l\varphi)\right) \,d\varphi$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^{2\pi} \left(\cos(m+n+l)\varphi+\cos(m+n-l)\varphi+\cos(m-n+l)\varphi+\cos(m-n-l)\varphi\right) \,d\varphi$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}\left[\frac{\sin(m+n+l)\varphi}{m+n+l}+\frac{\sin(m+n-l)\varphi}{m+n-l}+\frac{\sin(m-n+l)\varphi}{m-n+l}+\frac{\sin(m-n-l)\varphi}{m-n-l}\right]^{2\pi}_{0}$$
$$=0$$

Comment: We need to be careful with different cases, when one of $m \pm n \pm l = 0$.

Comment: @SimonS Yes. My answer will hold for $m\pm n\pm l \not =0$